# Delete item from database and listview on button click

Tags: java, android, database, listview, adapter

I'm trying to get an item deleted from both my custom listview and from the database on button click. I got so far but from the code below you are likely to see my error. When the first item is deleted the positions change however the idarray info is not updated. Please help!

History Adapter:

```
package uk.co.rascagneres.clocking_app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Jacques on 08/08/2016.
 */
public class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter{
    private  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<String> idArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    DatabaseHandler db;


    public HistoryAdapter (ArrayList<String> list, Context context, ArrayList<String> idArray, DatabaseHandler db){
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.idArray = idArray;
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos){
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos){
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list, null);
        }

        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                System.out.println(list.get(position));
                System.out.println(idArray.get(position));
                System.out.print(idArray);
                db.deleteRowID(Integer.parseInt(idArray.get(position)));
                list.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }



}
```

HistoryFragment:

```
package uk.co.rascagneres.clocking_app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Jacques on 03/08/2016.
 */
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {
    DatabaseHandler db;
    View myView;
    ArrayList<String> historyArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> idArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_layout, container, false);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        ArrayList<String> list = insertData();

        HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(list, getActivity(), idArray, db);

        ListView lView = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return myView;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> insertData(){
        Cursor c = db.getAllData();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            long in = c.getLong(1);
            long out = c.getLong(2);
            String outTime;

            if(out == 0){
                outTime = "N/A";
            }else{
                outTime = ClockingFragment.getDate(out, "HH:mm");
            }

            String date = ClockingFragment.getDate(in, "EEE, MMM d");
            String inTime = ClockingFragment.getDate(in, "HH:mm");

            historyArray.add(date + "\n Clocked In: " + inTime + "\n Clocked Out: " + outTime + "\n");
            idArray.add(String.valueOf(id));
        }

        if (historyArray.isEmpty()){
            historyArray.add("No History Available!");
        }

        return historyArray;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getIdArray(){
        System.out.println(idArray);
        return idArray;
    }

}
```

Section of Database Handler:

```
public void deleteRowID(int ID)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String IDString = String.valueOf(ID);
    try
    {
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] { IDString });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It works initially but once you delete the top one the positions change. Eg the item in position 2 is now in position 1. The idarray doesn't update obviously as insertData in the fragment hasn't been ran again so the ids and positions are now not synced up correctly.

Comment: I suggest extending `CursorAdapter` rather than `BaseAdapter`. It gives you a lot of the functionality you need to interact with a SQLite database.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it still doesn't help me get the ids of the items being printed into the list

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why do you need a list of the ids? And do you really need an `ArrayList`? Why isn't a `Cursor` sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the id array gets the ids in order of the output. The ids however aren't 1,2,3 etc. The id array is the ids of the items in the db.

Comment: It seems to me that you can do the same thing with a SQL query and a Cursor.